# Calling Function from another class swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Im having trouble calling a function in my GameViewController.swift from another class, Menu.swift.
I call the function like this:

```
class Menu: SKnode {

    func scoreAction(sender:UIButton!) { 
        self.buttonPlay.removeFromSuperview()
        self.buttonScore.removeFromSuperview()
         // CALLING FUNCTION
        GameViewController.showLeaderboard()    
     }
}
```

And here is the function I'm trying to call:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController,
 UITextFieldDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate  {

   func showLeaderboard()
    {
      var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
      gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

      gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
      gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "yourleaderboardid"

      self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

}

I have a Compiler Error inside my Menu class in the line GameViewController.showLeaderboard() 
"Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" But I don't understand what type of argument the compiler is expecting because I declared the function without any needing any parameters.

Thank you

Comment: You are trying to call showLeaderboard like a class method, but it is an instance method. You need to instantiate an instance of GameViewController  and then you can call showLeaderboard.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In `GameViewController` you have defined `scoreAction` as `instance` method not the `class` function.You should call `scoreAction` by making instance of `GameViewController`

```
class Menu: SKnode {

    func scoreAction(sender:UIButton!) { 
        self.buttonPlay.removeFromSuperview()
        self.buttonScore.removeFromSuperview()
         // CALLING FUNCTION 
         //see () on GameViewController
        GameViewController().showLeaderboard()    
     }
}
```

I think you should load `GameViewController` from storyBoard if you have `GameViewController` in storyBoard

Answer (score 12):

If you want to perform any method on action in another class, you have to use protocol.

//Outside 1st class

```
protocol abc {
     func xyz()
}
```

//Inside 1st class

```
var delegate: abc?
```

//Inside 1st class on action

```
self.delegate.xyz()
```

//Inside 2nd class you want to perform method

```
extension 2nd: abc {
    func xyz(){
      //code 
   }
}
```

//Inside 2nd class where the instantiate process is performed

```
let obj = 2nd() //2nd initialiser
obj.delegate = self

// if you want to use this scenario with table view cell in cellForRowAt
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
cell.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain what `2nd initialiser` inside `let obj = 2nd initialiser` is?

Comment: let obj = 2nd initialiser
Here obj is the object of 2nd initialiser like:-
 let cell = ?*(tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TVCSelectProfessionalForConsultation") as? TVCSelectProfessionalForConsultation) @ClassA