# Properties = nil when function called from another class BWWalkthrough

Tags: ios, swift, bwwalkthrough

I'm using [BWWalkthrough](https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough) to build a welcome walkthrough with textfield inside.

There are 2 prebuilt IBOutlets inside the `BWWalkthroughViewController` that I attached to my elements ( `nextButton` and `prevButton` ). Basically, I'm using textfields in my pages to ask them informations.

Inside the class of my page :

```
class WTnameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, BWWalkthroughPage {
```

I added an observer to see when the textfield change.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //  ...
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("textfieldIsNotEmpty:"), name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: textfieldName)
    //  ...
}
```

and it calls this function :

```
func textfieldIsNotEmpty(notification: NSNotification) {

    // BWWalkthroughViewController is the master class.
    let nxtBtn = BWWalkthroughViewController()

    if textfieldName.text?.isEmpty == true {
        // Animate the fade-out of the button
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            nxtBtn.nextButton?.layer.opacity = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                nxtBtn.nextButton?.hidden = true
        })

    } else if textfieldName.text?.isEmpty == false {
        // animate the fade-in of the button in BWWalkthrough
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            nxtBtn.nextButton?.hidden = false
            nxtBtn.nextButton?.layer.opacity = 1
            }, completion: { finished in
        })

    }
}
```

> But the button is a `nil`.

Also, I add a notification in ViewDidLoad of the the `BWWalkthroughViewController` class to change the position of the buttons

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

and the function :

```
func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    // Below we define the animation
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let convertedKeyboardEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardEndFrame, fromView: view.window)
    let rawAnimationCurve = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).unsignedIntValue << 16
    let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(rawAnimationCurve))

    // I change the constraint of the button with the animation
    buttonNextBottomConstraint!.constant = CGRectGetMaxY(view.bounds) - CGRectGetMinY(convertedKeyboardEndFrame)
    buttonBackBottomConstraint!.constant = CGRectGetMaxY(view.bounds) - CGRectGetMinY(convertedKeyboardEndFrame)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, animationCurve], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    // Here I check if 'nextButton' is a nil - Debug only
    print("keyboard : \(nextButton)")
}
```

> The value of `nextButton` *isn't* nil here

I also tried to change the button through functions directly inside the `BWWalkthroughViewController` but it also return me a `nil`.

Could someone explain me why `nextButton` is a nil in a function and not another one ?

**EDIT :**

I created the following function in the `BWWalkthroughViewController` :

```
public func textfieldChangeButton() {
        // Do stuff here when receive a notification about a textfield
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.nextButton?.hidden = false
            self.nextButton?.layer.opacity = 1
            print("textfieldChangeButton : \(self.nextButton)")
            }, completion: { finished in
        })
    }
```

When I call it from the actual `textfieldIsNotEmpty`, `nextButton` is `nil`, and when I call it from another function inside `BWWalkthroughViewController` directly, it works just fine.

Comment: What does the code look like in `textfieldIsNotEmpty` where you call the new function you have in the **EDIT** section?

Comment: I call it like that : `BWWalkthroughViewController().textfieldChangeButton()`.  Is that the wrong way to call it ?

Comment: I keep saying that `BWWalkthroughViewController()` creates a new, empty object...but you don't seem to believe me.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills I do believe you... Since this is exactly my error. I just followed the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082072/calling-function-from-another-class-swift) . How should I call the function then ?

Answer (score 1):

This: `let nxtBtn = BWWalkthroughViewController()` creates a new object.  Since it is not part of the screen display, it doesn't have its view loaded and therefore doesn't have its outlets filled in.

You don't say **how** `textfieldIsNotEmpty` is called but you probably want to pass it a reference to an existing `BWWalkthroughViewController` rather than having it create an empty one.

Comment: `textfieldIsNotEmpty` is called by the `NSNotification`, am I wrong ?

Plus, it makes sense so I tried replacing `nxtBtn.nextButton?.hidden = true` by `BWWalkthroughViewController().nextButton?.hidden = true`, and it didn't work either

Comment: Right about the notification...I was paying more attention to the target method.  But `BWWalkthroughViewController()` is still going to create a new, empty object whether it's on a line by itself or not.

Comment: I edited my answer with another approach. Thanks for your time.