# Swift, how to call a function in other viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My program has two controllers, CallerTableViewController, FunctionViewController

Caller is in CallerTableViewController and the function is in FunctionViewController

Now screen is displaying FunctionViewController while the calling program is in CallerTableViewController, the calling program should call the function in FunctionViewController

How can I call the function which is displaying on screen?

---

Update:

this is actual program

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class TableViewController: UITableViewController,
    CBCentralManagerDelegate,
    CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var centralManager:CBCentralManager!
    var connectingPeripheral:CBPeripheral!

    var bleDeviceName = [String]()
    var bleDevice=[CBPeripheral]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

        self.centralManager = centralManager;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bleDevice.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "oneCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = bleDeviceName[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        var peripheral=bleDevice[indexPath.row]

        self.centralManager.stopScan()
        connectingPeripheral = peripheral
        connectingPeripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(connectingPeripheral, options: nil)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("--- centralManagerDidUpdateState")
        switch central.state{
        case .poweredOn:

            let serviceUUIDs:[AnyObject] = [CBUUID(string: "1111")]
            let lastPeripherals = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: serviceUUIDs as! [CBUUID])

            print(lastPeripherals.count)

            if lastPeripherals.count > 0{
                print("count>0")
                let device = lastPeripherals.last! as CBPeripheral;
                connectingPeripheral = device;
                centralManager.connect(connectingPeripheral, options: nil)
            }
            else {
                centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil, options: nil)

            }
        case .poweredOff:
            print("--- central state is powered off")
        case .resetting:
            print("--- central state is resetting")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("--- central state is unauthorized")
        case .unknown:
            print("--- central state is unknown")
        case .unsupported:
            print("--- central state is unsupported")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("--- didDiscover peripheral")

        if let localName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String{

            bleDevice.append(peripheral)
            bleDeviceName.append(localName)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }else{
            print("!!!--- can't unwrap advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("--- didConnectPeripheral")

        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        print("--- peripheral state is \(peripheral.state)")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if (error) != nil{
            print("!!!--- error in didDiscoverServices: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            print("--- error in didDiscoverServices")
            for service in peripheral.services as [CBService]!{
                print("before disc chara"+service.uuid.uuidString)
                if service.uuid.uuidString=="11111111-1111-11111111-1111111111111" {
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
                    print("disc chara")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if (error) != nil{
            print("!!!--- error in didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            print("found charact: service"+service.uuid.uuidString)
            if service.uuid == CBUUID(string: "11111111-1111-11111111-1111111111111"){
                for characteristic in service.characteristics! as [CBCharacteristic]{

                    switch characteristic.uuid.uuidString{

                        case "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000":
                            print("Found Characteristic")
                            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)

                        default:
                            print()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
        //call function here
    }



}
```

// this is the function in FunctionViewController

```
func printTextField() {
    print(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: functionViewController.someFunction()  is what you need?

Comment: Without code it's kind of hard to know. (Hint: that would help very much.) How many view controllers are in your screen? Are you mixing up `UIViewController` and `UIView`? Should you be using a framework target? Are you using IB? Please, we should be able to help, but without some details of what you have....?

Comment: OK, I just updated the question, added my code, I use storyboard, no xib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Function from another class swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082072/calling-function-from-another-class-swift)

Comment: Are these 2 different View Controllers from 2 different screens? Or are both visible inside the same screen? Is one the child of the other?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is get the 'FunctionController' object . 

You can try this :

```
 let story = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORY_BOARD_NAME", bundle: Bundle.main);
 let fvc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER");
 fvc.someFunction();
```

You can find ***"YOUR_STORY_BOARD_NAME"*** on your file's list , usually to be "Main":

[image]

Choose your 'FunctionViewController' in the storyboard and find ***YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER*** here:

[image]

Comment: really...this wont work, it will create a new instance and will call the function of newly created instance instead of already existing view controller's.

Comment: oh , i know your problem now . You should find the view controller of 'FunctionViewController' object , this is the problem . If you switch to 'FunctionViewController' controller by self controller(usually) , you can find this object easy . if not , you should not call this function in 'FunctionViewController' , because if it's not create by self , you can not be sure if the 'FunctionViewController' object exists.

Comment: How to get the object? I use storyboard to connect these two views

Comment: @CLSo , I had update my Reply , i hope it can help you.

Comment: `instantiateViewController` will return UIViewController, so I change to `let fvc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FunctionViewController") as? FunctionViewController`, but this function still create a new instance, not the existing one

Comment: wait a minute , i give you the wrong function , sorry

Comment: You can create 'FunctionController' object by this way , and use ```self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender: nil);``` to switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

Class from where call back is to send  ->

```
 var dismissCallBackBlock: (() -> Void)?

   func dismissControllerCallBackBlock(completionBlock:@escaping () ->Void){
        dismissCallBackBlock = completionBlock
    }
```

Class where call back is received  ->

```
 classObj.dismissControllerCallBackBlock { (Bool) in

    }
```

Hope, it works.