# Custom cell did select not call delegate

Tags: swift

I have a custom cell named PendingHistoryCell. When did select i get my stake and by indexpath.row value of the id

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let userStakes = self.userStakes
        let better_bet_status = userStakes[indexPath.row].bet_status
        let deletedOddId = userStakes[indexPath.row]._id

        if better_bet_status == "PENDING" {
            delegate?.deleteBet(oddId: deletedOddId!)
        } else{

        }
    }
```

and the protocol is PendingHistoryCell

```
protocol PendingHistoryCellDelegate {
    func deleteBet(oddId: String)
}
```

And in MyBetsViewContoller i configure the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            //do some
        } else {
            let cell: PendingHistoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellId.MyBets.pendingHistoryCell, for: indexPath) as! PendingHistoryCell
            let match = isOnPendingTab ? pendingMatches[indexPath.row-1] : claimedMatches[indexPath.row-1]
            //let matchAllData = self.matchData
            let userStake = (self.matchData?.bets[indexPath.row-1].stakes)!
            //self.fixture = self.matchData?.bets[indexPath.row - 1].fixture

            if(self.matchData?.bets[indexPath.row - 1].fixture != nil){
                self.fixture = self.matchData?.bets[indexPath.row - 1].fixture!
            }

            //cell.configure(match: match, isPending: isOnPendingTab, betCount: self.betCount, matchData: matchAllData!, stakes: userStake, fixture:fixture!  )
            cell.configure(match: match,isPending: isOnPendingTab, betCount: self.betCount, stakes: userStake, fixture: fixture!)
//            func configure( isPending: Bool, betCount: Int,  stakes:[BT_Stake], fixture: BT_Fixture ) {

            return cell
        }
    }
```

and in my BetsViewController i called

```
extension MyBetsViewController: PendingHistoryCellDelegate {

    func deleteBet(oddId: String) {
        //do some()
    }

}
```

but delegates method does not call.

Comment: where are you assigning the delegate ?

Comment: `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961356/5857254

Comment: You can check the above link as your protocol initializer is not in the cell. It is in the controller according to your above code. For the above what you need to achieve doesn't need any protocol. You can easily do the above by calling a function.

Comment: Moreover, if you want some action from your cell you need to create the initializer in TableViewCell class and then assign cell.delegate = self in cellForRowAt

Comment: I think you are not assigning delegate, you can add `cell.delegateVariableforProtocol = self` in `cellForRowAt` method

Comment: I have forgot to assigning before configure. Thanks it worked.

Comment: @PratyushPratik in my PendingCell i use another cell MyBetsTableViewCell an in its didSelect method that is why i use it  use delegate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, you need to add the delegate to your tableview cell.  To do this, your cell needs the following (in your cell class) :

```
weak var delegate: PendingHistoryCellDelegate?
```

To be declared weak (and avoid potential memory leaks), your protocol needs to add : class to its declaration:

```
protocol PendingHistoryCellDelegate: class {
```

You can then assign the delegate to your tableview cell in the cellForRow method:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: The only missing part was cell.delegate = self. Thanks anyway.